# Magento 2 - How to use the sales model in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, orders, model

I've created a new module and I need the functionality from the Magento\Sales\Model\Order model to fetch a list of all orders.

How can I use this model within my own module?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using the model, Magento recommends using API. 
You can use following sample code to get some insight and modify according to your requirement.

```
namespace Path\To\Your\Class;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class YourClass extends \ParentClas\Path
{
    ---
    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    ---

    /**
     * ---
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteria
     * ---
     */
    public function __construct(
        ---
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteria
        ---
    ) {
        ---
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteria
        ---
    }

    public function yourMethod(){
        $records = $this->orderRepository->getList(
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->create()
        );
    }
}
```